# Tradução das medalhas Fanático e Entusiasta

Tags: debate, tradução, medalhas

A tradução da medalha `Fanático` está com o seguinte texto

> Visitou o site 100 por dias consecutivos. (Dias contados no fuso UTC.)

Acredito que o valor 100 esteja incorretamente posicionado no texto. Ficando de maneira mais acertiva:

> Visitou o site por 100 dias consecutivos. (Dias contados no fuso UTC.)

O mesmo é valido para a medalha `Entusiasta`, que tem esse mesmo problema:

> Visitou o site 30 por dias consecutivos. (Dias contados no fuso UTC.)

Comment: Caramba, todo esse tempo e ninguém notou isso Oo

Comment: Leitura dinâmica full power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adicionei a sugestão no [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-pt). Só falta ser revisado pelos administradores e aí vai pra "produção".

Comment: Observei hoje e a medalha continua com o mesmo nome.